# d3.js closing an arc (donut) using transition does not behave as expected

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to close an arc, making it into a donut, using a transition and it goes out of whack for a second.

If I don't use a transition, both ends meet without a glitch. However, using transition(), the moment one end touches the other, the shape becomes a solid circle, goes off to the left, and then goes back to being a donut on the right coordinates.

Why does this happen and how can I avoid it?

Here's the part that creates the circle:

```
        this.arcSvg = d3.svg.arc()
        .innerRadius(200)
        .outerRadius(250)
        .startAngle(function(context) {
            var self = context;
            return function(d) {
                return self.scale(d.start) * Math.PI;
            };
        }(this))
        .endAngle(function(context) {
            var self = context;
            return function(d) {
                return self.scale(d.end) * Math.PI;
            };
        }(this));


    this.arc = this.graph.selectAll("path")
        .data(this.data)
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr("d", this.arcSvg);
```

Here's the part that does the update and the transition:

```
        this.data = data;
        this.arc.transition().ease("linear").attr("d", this.arcSvg);
```

Comment: please create a sample of the problem at jsfiddle.com.  thanks.

Comment: Have you seen [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1346410)? You can't use out of the box transitions with arcs.